# How to use python matplotlib to get the CMYK graph, not the RGB?

Tags: python, matplotlib, rgb, cmyk

I'm using matplotlib to obtain data graph, but I do not know the default setting of color format, RGB or CMYK? if not the RGB, how can I set CMYK in matplotlib code? Thank u all!

Comment: I think matplotlib can't use CMYK.

Comment: Thanks，it seems taht only I can do is using photoshop

Comment: Maybe other module in Python could convert RGB/RGBA to CMYK but I don't know which one.